# Postgres + Go + Docker-compose Can't ping database: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

It is not my golang script, but i should to use them in this task:
package main

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/caarlos0/env"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

type config struct {
    PostgresUri   string `env:"POSTGRES_URI" envDefault:"postgres://root:pass@127.0.0.1/postgres"`
    ListenAddress string `env:"LISTEN_ADDRESS" envDefault:":5432"`
}

var (
    db          *sql.DB
    errorsCount = prometheus.NewCounterVec(
        prometheus.CounterOpts{
            Name: "gocalc_errors_count",
            Help: "Gocalc Errors Count Per Type",
        },
        []string{"type"},
    )

    requestsCount = prometheus.NewCounter(
        prometheus.CounterOpts{
            Name: "gocalc_requests_count",
            Help: "Gocalc Requests Count",
        })
)

func main() {
    var err error

    // Initing prometheus
    prometheus.MustRegister(errorsCount)
    prometheus.MustRegister(requestsCount)

    // Getting env
    cfg := config{}
    if err = env.Parse(&cfg); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
    }

    // Connecting to database
    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", cfg.PostgresUri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't connect to postgresql: %v", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't ping database: %v", err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(cfg.ListenAddress, nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    requestsCount.Inc()

    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["q"]
    if !ok || len(keys[0]) < 1 {
        errorsCount.WithLabelValues("missing").Inc()
        log.Println("Url Param 'q' is missing")
        http.Error(w, "Bad Request", 400)
        return
    }
    q := keys[0]
    log.Println("Got query: ", q)

    var result string
    sqlStatement := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT (%s)::numeric", q)
    row := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement)
    err := row.Scan(&result)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error from db: %s", err)
        errorsCount.WithLabelValues("db").Inc()
        http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "query %s; result %s", q, result)
}
```

It is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
    expose:
      - 5432
    
  backend:
    image: dkr-14-gocalc:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_URI=postgres://root:pass@db/postgres
      - LISTEN_ADDRESS=7000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./nginx.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on: 
      - backend
```

And it is dkr14-gocalc image:

```
FROM golang:1.19.1-alpine AS builder
ENV GO111MODULE=auto
WORKDIR /go/src/

RUN apk add --no-cache git 
COPY main.go ./
 
#init is initializing and writting new go.mod in current dir.
RUN go mod init main.go

RUN go get -d -v github.com/caarlos0/env \
    && go get -d -v github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus \
    && go get -d -v github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp \
    && go get -d -v github.com/lib/pq \   
    && go get -d -v database/sql \
    && go get -d -v fmt \
    && go get -d -v log \
    && go get -d -v net/http
    
RUN go build -o app .

FROM alpine:3.10.3
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/app ./
CMD ["./app"]
```

I should to make docker compose environment with 3 services GO+POSTGRES+NGINX. The main idea of task is to learn about environment. Database should have password and golalc should to connect to this database. But what have i done  incorrect?

It is my log:

```
backend_1   | 2022/11/07 23:27:33 Can't ping database: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
postgres_1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres_1  | This user must also own the server process.
postgres_1  | 
proxy_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
proxy_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
postgres_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
proxy_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
proxy_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
postgres_1  | 
task14_backend_1 exited with code 1
proxy_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
postgres_1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres_1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
proxy_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
postgres_1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
proxy_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
postgres_1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres_1  | selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
postgres_1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
proxy_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
postgres_1  | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres_1  | running bootstrap script ... ok
postgres_1  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres_1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres_1  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgres_1  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
proxy_1     | 2022/11/07 23:27:33 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "backend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:5
proxy_1     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:5
postgres_1  | waiting for server to start....2022-11-07 23:27:33.704 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:33.722 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-11-07 23:27:33 UTC
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:33.729 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1  |  done
postgres_1  | server started
task14_proxy_1 exited with code 1
postgres_1  | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.130 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1  | waiting for server to shut down....2022-11-07 23:27:34.133 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.135 UTC [48] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.135 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.157 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1  |  done
postgres_1  | server stopped
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.254 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.254 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.259 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.283 UTC [76] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-11-07 23:27:34 UTC
postgres_1  | 2022-11-07 23:27:34.294 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be in how you're exposing your database container in the `docker-compose.yaml` file. "connection refused" is a typical error in this scenario. Usually, I export the ports in a different way (in this code I reported only the relevant parts):

##### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

##### main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    // Connecting to database
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't connect to postgresql: %v", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Can't ping database: %v", err)
    }
}
```

With this solution, I was able to successfully ping the Postgres database directly from the code. Let me know if that helps.

#### Edit

There is a little difference in the way you interact with db instance:

1. If you're trying to contact the db directly from your host machine (like in the `main.go` file), you've to refer to it with the IP address of your machine (e.g., `127.0.0.1`).
2. If you're trying to contact the db from your web container, you've to use something like `postgres://db:5432` with `db` as the hostname.

Let me know if this clarifies a little bit.

Comment: I did this, but instead of localhost i have used db, because it is name of container with Postgres. Now i have following error: `listen tcp: address 5432: missing port in address`
It is my envs:
`POSTGRES_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable,  LISTEN_ADDRESS=5432`

Comment: Response just updated!

Comment: Thank you, it is help me. But now I have another problem with nginx. Maybe you can help me, check another question in my profile)